# Fading line using gradient tool in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, line-art

I have a vertical line to fade from both the sides that is **Top and Bottom**.

## My try:

I have followed these steps:

Step 1. Own layer for line.
Step 2. Added Layer Mask to the layer.
Step 3. Selected the gradient tool.
Step 4. Clicked and dragged the gradient on the layer mask.

**Problem**: If I drag the gradient tool on the layer in top part of the line it's done. But when I move to the bottom side the top part is getting deselected.

How to overcome with this?

Thanks

Comment: Fade from both of which sides? Top and bottom? Left and right? Welcome to GraphicDesign!

Comment: @ZachSaucier, Thank you. Yeah its Top and bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be certain to use a **black to transparent** gradient on the layer mask.

Using a black to white gradient will paint over existing areas you may want masked.

Comment: I apologize! But did't get yet. Any picture will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Scott's right. To clarify, use the **black to transparent** gradient next to the **black to white** gradient in the gradients panel:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. But I need to accept Scott answer as per FIFO concept, but upvote for you is sure. :)